# How to decrypt zip file programmatically in as 400 using RPG/RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Is is possible to decrypt a zip file in AS 400 with password using RPG/RPGLE? Which library I should use? Is there any example?

Comment: Put your ZIP file on a IFS, add any C++ ZIP decrype library (zlib) and call the C++ function in your RPGLE programm

Comment: Thx, will try it

Answer (score 2):

It's simplere then ever.

Just use Jar in a QSH Command to unzip files:

ex. QSH CMD('cd /dest_dir;jar -xvf /your_dir/fileName.zip')

You can embed it in a CL Program or an RPGLE (using "system").

Here is the official link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=nas8N1015312

Comment: But how do you specify a password to unzip a password-protected file?